# How to get the last character of a string in an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the last character of strings in an array like this:

```
Down = ["up 1", "up 2", "up 3"]
```

I want to receive the `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`, and make a conditional statement like `for.each` based on the result, which would run this logic:

- If the final character is `"1"`, let `@x` = `0`
- If the final character is `"2"`, let `@x` = `1`
- If the final character is `"3"`, let `@x` = `2`

Comment: Can you post what u have tried so far?

Comment: What is `for.each`?

Comment: You can do `down.map { |str| str[/\d+\z/] }` in case of numbers more than a single-digit. Also variable names should be all lower-case and why is it called down, when it contains strings with all `"up"`s!?

Answer (score 3):

your variable name should not start with Capital letter,

```
> down = ["up 1", "up 2", "up 3"]
> numbers_ary = down.map{|s|s[-1]}
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

**OR**

```
> numbers_ary = down.map{|s| s.chars.last}
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

> make a conditional statement like for.each based on the result

If you make a loop of an array and assign value to same variable `@x` using any logic, it will be override and assign last value.

But as per your concern of logic, can do this way:

```
num = numbers_ary.sample #sample is used to pick random element from numbers_ary
case num
  when "1", "2", "3"
   @x = num.to_i - 1
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer below has a rails dependency. To remove that dependency, change `down.last` to `down.chars.last` or `down[-1]`

```
Down.each do |down|
  case(down.last)
  when '1'
   @x = 0
  when '2'
   @x = 1
  when '3'
   @x =2
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: I am adding the output I got after running this on the irb console for the people who are adding comment about me running this before I posted this answer and downvoting this answer without any clear comments.

```
irb(main):014:0> Down=["up 1", "up 2", "up 3"]
=> ["up 1", "up 2", "up 3"]
irb(main):015:0> Down.each do |down|
irb(main):016:1* case(down.last)
irb(main):017:2> when '1'
irb(main):018:2> @x = 0
irb(main):019:2> puts "word: #{down}, last:#{down.last}, x: #{@x}"
irb(main):020:2> when '2'
irb(main):021:2> @x = 1
irb(main):022:2> puts "word: #{down}, last:#{down.last}, x: #{@x}"
irb(main):023:2> when '3'
irb(main):024:2> @x = 2
irb(main):025:2> puts "word: #{down}, last:#{down.last}, x: #{@x}"
irb(main):026:2> end
irb(main):027:1> end
word: up 1, last:1, x: 0
word: up 2, last:2, x: 1
word: up 3, last:3, x: 2
=> ["up 1", "up 2", "up 3"]
```

Comment: Did you run this before adding it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I did run it. Why are you asking? and whoever down voted this answer. Please let me know why

Comment: @SebastianPalma please see the output above

Comment: I don't know which Ruby version you're using, or any other factor that makes the difference. See the [output](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/7fb7af2a91d67fc15b8db246fa19719e), also in the irb using Ruby 2.4.1. Anyways, I'm not a downvoter here.

Comment: @MarkThomas, Please see the output. Its doing exactly what I think i.e returning last character of the string. Anyways, I know why it is working for me and not you guys. `> String.new.method(:last).source_location
=> ["/home/xeon/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb", 95]`

Comment: Basically, I copy pasted it to the console I had open which has the `active_support` library pre loaded.

Comment: So basically your answer has a Rails dependency which you didn't mention

Comment: Correct, I will edit my post. Also, does the answer need to be spoon feed. It needs to work when I copy paste it otherwise it is incorrect. Did you guys ever learn to write pseudo code (no offense intended). What about the logic behind the given answer

Comment: No, the answer shouldn't be spoon-fed. In my opinion, answers to questions that have absolutely no attempt to solve the problem should consist only of hints, not working solutions.

Comment: @MarkThomas +1. Also, edited the answer to include rails dependency and how to remove that dependency